# How to configure model to use calculated values in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have to work with a MySQL database where in one of tables there's a column containing list of foreign keys formatted in specific way. It looks like so:

| id | value | type | path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 1 |  |
| 2 | bbb | 2 | /1 |
| 3 | ccc | 3 | /1/2 |
| 4 | ddd | 4 | /1/2/3 |
| 5 | eee | 3 | /1/2 |
| 6 | fff | 4 | /1/2/5 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Obviously, it isn't most convinient. Number of these foreign keys is limited so I tried splitting `path` into several values. Query like so seems to do the job and give me all values I need:

```sql
SELECT *, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(path,'/',-1) as parent,
    SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(path,'/',2) FROM 2) as first,
    SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(path,'/',3) FROM 2 + LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(path,'/',2))) as second,
    SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(path,'/',4) FROM 2 + LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(path,'/',3))) as third
FROM table_name;
```

giving me results like this:

| id | value | type | path | parent | first | second | third |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | bbb | 2 | /1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| 3 | ccc | 3 | /1/2 | 2 | 1 | 2 |  |
| 4 | ddd | 4 | /1/2/3 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

In my project I'm using Entity Framework Core and I would like to use a model like so:

```cs
class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public TypeEnum Type { get; set; }
    public int[] Path { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public int? FirstId { get; set; }
    public int? SecondId { get; set; }
    public int? ThirdId { get; set; }
}
```

I have no problems with properties that actually exist in this table. Now, my question is: **how to configure model builder for that entity to behave like query above and fill values of foreign keys?**

I have tried or considered several solutions or workarounds but neither seems to be perfect:

1. Most obvious one - creating a view on database. While it would work fine, I don't want to modify the database schema - it is currently used by other application and managed by its migration system.
2. Computed columns - configuring these properties using `HasComputedColumnSql()` - it still requires for that column to exist in database. And for reasons mentioned modifying table is even worse than adding view.
3. Using LINQ `Select()` or even `FromSqlRaw()` - while doesn't require modifying schema it would require adding a lot of code since model in question isn't really queried directly but rather exists as child of another entity.

Ideal solution would be, as said, configuring model builder in a way it would always include these properties in generated queries for the model.

I might end up writing all selects required but wanted to search for more elegant solution first.

Comment: Perhaps the [interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Define and register function mapping for `SUBSTRING_INDEX`

```cs
public static class MySqlFunctions
{
    public static string SUBSTRING_INDEX(string value, string delimiter, int number)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

```cs
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => MySqlFunctions.SUBSTRING_INDEX("", "", 1))
    .HasName("SUBSTRING_INDEX");
```

Create function which returns needed fields as LINQ Query:

```cs
public IQueryable<Model> WithParsedPath()
{
    return table_name
        .Select(e => new Model
        {
            Id = e.Id,
            Value = e.Value,
            Type = e.Type,

            ParentId = Convert.ToInt32(MySqlFunctions.SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.path, "/", -1)),
            FirstId  = Convert.ToInt32(MySqlFunctions.SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.path, "/", 2).Substring(1)),
            SecondId = Convert.ToInt32(MySqlFunctions.SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.path, "/", 3).Substring(1 + MySqlFunctions.SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.path, "/", 2).Length)),
            ThirdId  = Convert.ToInt32(MySqlFunctions.SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.path, "/", 4).Substring(1 + MySqlFunctions.SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.path, "/", 3).Length)),
        });
}
```

Function will return zeroes for invalid Ids, but i think it should not be a problem.

Comment: It's basically variant of my 3rd solution - you're not changing how EF builds the entity but using `Select()` to fill extra fields. I would need to call `WithParsedPath()` every time different entity has children of type `Model`. My question is how to avoid this.

Comment: You can't. And why avoid? It is normal performant solution. It is like a View without view.

Comment: You can make property from this method and put into DbContext.

Comment: View is written once and every time you query data EF fills all the fields. If I want entities of type `ModelB` with children `Children` of type `List<Model>` I can simply use `Include(x => x.Children)`. With this solution each time I would have to manually write `Select` or `Join` for `ModelB` to include missing fields of the `Model`

Comment: How often you need Include?  Write once Select which loads children. I'm also lazy but efforts to make it work as you which is too high.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, with help of [Alexander Petrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5045688/alexander-petrov)'s comment:

> Perhaps the [interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) will help you.

I ended up with following solution:

## Use interceptor to replace table in queries with SELECT statement

which was realized with following class:

```cs
public class PseudoViewInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    private readonly string _tableName;
    private readonly string _replacementSelect;
    private readonly string _dummyReplacement = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public PseudoViewInterceptor(string tableName, string replacementSelect)
    {
        _tableName = tableName;
        _replacementSelect = replacementSelect;
    }

    public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
    {
        ManipulateCommand(command);
        return result;
    }

    public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, 
        InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        ManipulateCommand(command);
        return new ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>>(result);
    }

    private void ManipulateCommand(DbCommand command)
    {
        if(command.CommandText.Contains(_tableName))
        {
            command.CommandText = command.CommandText
                .Replace($"FROM `{_tableName}` AS", $"FROM ({_dummyReplacement}) AS")
                .Replace($"JOIN `{_tableName}` AS", $"JOIN ({_dummyReplacement}) AS")
                .Replace(_dummyReplacement, _replacementSelect);
        }
    }
}
```

This interceptor takes every command DbContext executes and searches it for `tableName`. If it finds it, it reaplaces every occurence where commands used `FROM ... AS` or `JOIN ... AS` on that table with `replacementSelect`.

In case of given example instance of interceptor should be created with `tableName` equal to `"table_name"` and `replacementSelect` with query from the question (minus semicolon at the end).

The model builder will behave as if it was provided with needed view, without actually creating one.